# Pass instance of type from argument list into function declaration (dynamic environment capture)

Tags: arguments, global-variables, rust

I made a library that implements an optimization algorithm [here](https://github.com/pengowen123/cmaes). These are the signatures for the relevant function and trait:

```
pub fn cmaes_loop<T>(object: &T, options: CMAESOptions) -> Option<Vec<f64>>
    where T: 'static + FitnessFunction

pub trait FitnessFunction {
    fn get_fitness(&self, parameters: &[f64]) -> f64;
}
```

If I apply the library to a simple problem, I can calculate the fitness based on the parameters given. However, let's say I want to optimize the shape of a wing for a given size and material:

```
struct Wing<'a> {
    material: String,
    size: i32,
    parameters: &'a [f64]
}
```

I can implement the fitness function to read from the other fields and factor them into the calculation, then give an instance of `Wing` to the `cmaes_loop` function to optimize a specific material and size. I am making another library that will use this one. It optimizes something else (like `Wing`), so I have a wrapper trait to make the second library easier to use:

```
pub trait WingFitnessFunction {
    fn get_fitness(&self, wing: &Wing) -> f64;
}
```

I implement the `FitnessFunction` trait like this:

```
impl FitnessFunction for Wing {
    fn get_fitness(&self, parameters: &[f64]) -> f64 {
        let wing = Wing {
            parameters: parameters,
            .. self
        };

        // error here
        let result = WingFitnessFunction::get_fitness(wing);
    }
}
```

`WingFitnessFunction` has a `&self` argument for the the same reason `FitnessFunction` does. I want a user of my second library to be able to pass an instance of their type that implements the `WingFitnessFunction`. I put the `impl` of `FitnessFunction` into the body of a function that takes an instance of the user's type:

```
fn foo<T: WingFitnessFunction>(object: T) {
    impl FitnessFunction for Wing {
        ...
        object.get_fitness(wing)
    }
```

But  when I try to call the `get_fitness` method of `object` I get this error:

> can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the || { ... } closure form instead

I need to know how to call `object`'s `get_fitness` method on a specific instance (a closure could do this, but I do not know how I would make it work with the `cmaes_loop` function).

Comment: This is a poor question because the problem is not described clearly enough for an answerer to understand it. There's not an obvious parallel between your first example (where the "extra" data is static) and the trait-based example (where it's a member of a struct). Consider whether you may have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can't generalize the question, at least provide an example with enough code for potential answerers to grasp the context.

Comment: @trencl, Thanks for the suggestion, the question should be better now because it has a clearer example describing my specific case and problem.

Comment: Thank you for improving your question! So few people do. It's still not clear to me why `WingFitnessFunction` is a trait, though, since it doesn't have any methods (functions with `self`). I'm with you right up until "It optimizes something else..." Can you explain why and how a user would implement `WingFitnessFunction` instead of just implementing `FitnessFunction` directly?

Comment: @trentcl, I meant to add `self` to it, fixed. The reason a user would implement `WingFitnessFunction` is because it makes it easier to use, and it guarantees the users doesn't break anything. I have two libraries: an optimization algorithm with the `FitnessFunction` trait, and another optimization algorithm that in this example would optimize the material and size of wings. If a user implemented the `FitnessFunction` trait directly, it would mean they have to set parameters manually and work with my wrapper struct in my answer.

Comment: @trentcl, To implement `WingFitnessFunction`, the user would make a function that reads the material, size, and parameters of the wing given as an argument, then returns its fitness. The second library uses an algorithm that would generate many different wings, and use my first library to optimize their parameters. In my use case the user would simply use a method on the `Wing` struct and calculate fitness based on the result, so it will be much simpler. The point is for the user to judge the fitness not based on the parameter values themselves, but in an indirect way.

Comment: Ah! All is clear now. Glad to see you have resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to my problem is to add a wrapper:

```
struct WingWrapper<'a, T: WingFitnessFunction> {
    wing: Wing,
    object: T
}
```

And implement `FitnessFunction` for it:

```
impl<'a, T: WingFitnessFunction> FitnessFunction for WingWrapper<'a, T> {
    fn get_fitness(&self, parameters: &[f64]) -> f64 {
        let wing = Wing {
            parameters: parameters,
            .. self.wing
        }

        self.object.get_fitness(&wing)
    }
}
```

In the function that takes a type that implements `WingFitnessFunction` as an argument, first build a `WingWrapper`:

```
let wrapper = WingWrapper {
    wing: // Instance of wing here
    object: // Instance of object here (taken as an argument)
}
```

Now, you can call the `get_fitness` method from the `WingFitnessFunction` trait through the method from `FitnessFunction`:

```
println!("{}", wrapper.get_fitness(&[1, 2, 3]));
```

This does not add any difficult to using the library; it is exactly the same from the user's perspective.